# Didn't find class "edu.stanford.cs231m.HelloAndroidActivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to implement the "HelloAndroid" according to Stanford mobile computer vision course http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs231m/. I'm running into the "ClassNotFoundException" problem. On the android emulator it says "Unfortunately, HelloAndroid has stopped." The LogCat in Eclipse shows the following:

```
04-17 22:28:47.180: D/AndroidRuntime(2036): Shutting down VM
04-17 22:28:47.180: D/AndroidRuntime(2036): --------- beginning of crash
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): Process: edu.stanford.cs231m, PID: 2036
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{edu.stanford.cs231m/edu.stanford.cs231m.HelloAndroidActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "edu.stanford.cs231m.HelloAndroidActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.stanford.cs231m-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2209)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "edu.stanford.cs231m.HelloAndroidActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/edu.stanford.cs231m-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1065)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2199)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     ... 10 more
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: edu.stanford.cs231m.HelloAndroidActivity
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):         at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):         at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):         at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):         ... 13 more
04-17 22:28:47.180: E/AndroidRuntime(2036):     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

For reference, the java code is

```
package edu.stanford.cs231m.helloandroid;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        TextView txtView = new TextView(this);
        txtView.setText("Hello czAndroid!");
        setContentView(txtView);

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

And the manifest.xml is

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="edu.stanford.cs231m"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <activity 
        android:name="HelloAndroidActivity" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>

</manifest>
```

The project windows is like
[image]

The emulator detail is as follows, if that matters:

[image]

And the java build path is
[image]

I have worked on this for almost a day, and tried methods like adding a dot to "HelloAndroidActivity", select all items in the java build path etc., but none of these works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my package name for manifest.xml was written incorrectly. I wrote

```
package="edu.stanford.cs231m"
```

The correct one should be

```
package="edu.stanford.cs231m.helloandroid"
```

And problem was solved.